# What are the differences between these ways of setting a property?

Tags: c#, get, set, member, c#-6.0

What are the differences between these examples?

```
//example A
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Limited Edition Item"
}
```

```
//example B
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; } => "Limited Edition Item"
}
```

```
//example C
public class Product
{
    public string Name => "Limited Edition Item"
}
```

Is example A just a get set property with a default value?
Is there a difference between example A and example B?
Can example C be set or is it strictly a get?

Answer (score 0):

When compiled, the get method is generated differently.

**Example A** will give you the same value every time you call it

**Example B & C** will give you a new value each time you call it.

**Example C** will not be settable and will return a new value each time you call it.

So:

```
public object Value { get; } = // This uses the same reference
public object Value => // This uses a new reference
```